# How to train multiple independent models in a parallel way?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

For example,

```py
num = 100
for i in range(num):
    model[i].fit(X,Y)
```

I have `num` models to be trained using the same data `X, Y`. Here `model` is of type `dict()`and all `model[i]` are independent with each other. How to reduce the time cost of this code in a parallel way via python packages?

To help answer this question, you might substitute `model[i].fit(X,Y)` with `print(i)`

```py
num = 100
for i in range(num):
    print(i)
```

You can use `multiprocessing`, `numba` or any other package that you're familiar with.

Comment: This looks like a homework question? what have you tried?

Comment: What library are you using for your model?

Comment: @FChm Hi, I've tried `joblib` but it costs 1072 seconds, even more than original 1030 seconds that without speeding.

Comment: @markuscosinus My model is built via `from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor`, and `model = dict()`, then `for i in range(100): model[i]=GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=20)`